# PHP Coding for downloading the image

Tags: php

[image: Browser download location]
In the website page contains many images with downloading options. If I click the download button it automatically downloaded on user system and it shows on browser downloadable page. I have PHP code like

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://website.com/images/logo.png');
file_put_contents('C:/Users/ASUS/Downloads/image.jpg', $image);
```

Above coding is working fine. But I need to provide the path name for image to save. In user side we don`t know the path.

I need the PHP code to use the browser download location and download images need to show the browser downloads.

Comment: The server will never be able to know where the end user browser is downloading files surely? They'll just default to the end users browser downloads path.

Comment: @ Simon Bosley See my attachment image(Chrome). Need to take the browser download location path

Answer (score 0):

you have to save/download the image somewhere on your web serwer and next send the file to user using header function, for example:

```
$file = 'path_to_image';
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
else {
    echo "file not exists";
}
```

[image]

[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: @sathish any warrning? for test make new .php file only with this code. 
Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent.

Comment: @ssnake no warning But code is not working. I check the manual link also

Comment: @sathish add `else` statment or check what returns  `echo file_exists($file);`

Comment: `<?php 
   $filename =''http://website.com/images/logo.png'; 
   $size = @getimagesize($filename); 
   $fp = @fopen($filename, "rb"); 
   if ($size && $fp) 
   { 
      header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}"); 
      header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename)); 
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');  
   
      fpassthru($fp); 
      exit; 
   } 
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");  
?>`

Answer (score 0):

not possible to store the image in particular user location due to security issues .you don't force user .you have to suggest him to store particular location .and also you don't know the what file system there in user system.and also downloading path can be setting up by user anywhere so your not able to get that.

Comment: i think its possible. If i download the attachment in gmail and  its automatically downloaded and save in my downloads folder(browser download location)

Comment: yeah its general thing .but user can change the path anywhere .so browser know where to save the file (where user given path ) but we don't know that path where it is.

Comment: possible thing is you have to suggest the user to particular path

Comment: your not able to change the downloading path in browser @sathish

Comment: yes its correct. i suggest the user to particular path

Comment: if you  get the result for your question .mark it with green tick because its useful to future users @sathish

Comment: suggestion means you just show any message  to user on particular page  .@sathish

Answer (score 0):

```
   $filename = '/images/'.basename($_POST['text']);
   file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Comment: Rather than just pasting a random bunch of code, explain what you did and why. That way, the OP and any future readers with the same problem can actually learn something from your answer, rather than just copy/pasting it and asking the same question again tomorrow.

Comment: dear @Oldskool   ok i explain what does my code... in the first line i take file name .. ok and in second line i use file_put_content function for write the content into a file... in that i pass two parameter ,, first is filename and second is content ... and this is not copy paste , i use this code in my project and it is work..  i hope now u understand and not say anything that it is copy/paste...

Answer (score 0):

```
`<?php  
   $filename ='http://website.com/images/logo.png'; 
   $size = @getimagesize($filename); 
   $fp = @fopen($filename, "rb"); 
   if ($size && $fp) 
   { 
      header("Content-type: {$size['mime']}"); 
      header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename)); 
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename"); 
      header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'); 
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');        
      fpassthru($fp); 
      exit; 
   } 
   header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); 
?>`
```